# how to stop New next node has connection to it's previous, trying previous again

Tags: ignite

we have a lot of logs in Ignite that showing New next node has connection to it's previous, trying previous again.

As we have 8 nodes in the ignite cluster, in one node, the log shows it

org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - New next node
org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - New next node has connection to it's previous, trying previous again.

however the previous has issue to be connected, after that, it will be again showing
org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - New next node
org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - New next node has connection to it's previous, trying previous again.

this occurs for a couple of time, the node itself got segmented.

is there a way to stop this behavior to try previous and always do the new node if it failed?

I've tried to use the default setting for discoverySpi.setConnectionRecoveryTimeout(); which was 0

but this was originally the issue happened.

then i tried to give it discoverySpi.setConnectionRecoveryTimeout(30000);

however this still persist.

I've tried to read all the docs but it was not mentioned anyway something related.

Anyone has any hints?

Comment: If a node gets segmented, you need to restart it. Is there anything else in the logs? Either a networking issue or a "Long JVM pause" perhaps?

Comment: We've switched to ZGC, hence the Long JVM pause was gone long time ago, this issue has nothing to do with JVM pause.

Comment: from the logs, I dont see anything related to networking, but i suspect it's networking, but for my case, i setup the cluster in different vms, the nodes drops from time to time, where i dont see there's anything in the docs that explains it. those vms are actually within one intranet, i've never experienced anything like this for our other app clusters.

Comment: @zizippp, you can try to check connectivity between the nodes by using `control.sh --diagnostic connectivity` command, to be sure that each node is able to establish connection with others.

Comment: very odd that it's stable for 2 weeks since then but i haven't done anything.